# mysql like query for at least one word from searched string

Tags: sql, mysql

I try to write a mysql query that search in column values from any keyword matching from string or full string
like search "google tag manager" from post table my query is like below

```
select * from wp_post where post_title like "%google tag manager%" and post_status = "publish";
```

But not getting expected result it shows post that has "google tag manager" in title. I also need posts that has "Google" in title or "Tag" or "Manager" in title
Please help me to update this query.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `(like '%google%'  or like '%tag%' or like '%manager%")`